# Javascript LocalForage returning length as null

Tags: javascript, html, promise, local-storage, localforage

I'm using [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) to store data as key-object pairs. I'm using the following code to retrieve the data I have already stored.

```
// Find the number of items in the datastore.
localforage.length(function(length) {
    // Loop over each of the items.
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // Get the key.
        localforage.key(i, function(key) {
            // Retrieve the data.
               localforage.getItem(key, function(value){
                   //do stuff
               });
        });
    }
});
```

(I found out about localforage and took the above code snippet from [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-localforage-offline-data-storage).)

This was not working, so I put `console.log()` after `localforage.length()`

```
 // Find the number of items in the datastore.
    localforage.length(function(length) {
        console.log(length);
        // Loop over each of the items.
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            // Get the key.
            localforage.key(i, function(key) {
                // Retrieve the data.
                   localforage.getItem(key, function(value)
                       //do stuff
                   });
            });
        }
    });
```

Turns out `console.log(length)` gives `null`, so it seems the for loop beneath it never gets executed. However after loading the webpage if I manually type in `localforage.length();` in the Chrome developer tools console it returns the following:

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
__proto__:Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]:"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]:2
```

Which makes sense as I have 2 objects stored currently. So why is my code snippet not working and why is length returned as `null`? I feel this has something to do with promises which I am unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, localForage is an asynchronous API, so it either works with callbacks or Promises.

You need to extract the value from the promise by using `.then` after the `localforage.length`

`localforage.length().then(function(length) { .....`

Here are the docs for .length as well: http://localforage.github.io/localForage/#data-api-length

Comment: The `.length()` function, as documented, does allow a callback however. The API supports either mechanism.

Comment: @Pointy exactly my thought.

Comment: `localforage.length(function(error, length)` first parameter for a callback is usually an error, so it is null presumably because there was no error. If you don't understand promises fully you can try that